# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols; calling functions with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, struct, swiftui, watchos

I have a Swift UI struct called MyWatchView with this stack.

```
        VStack (alignment: .center)
        {
            HStack
            {
                Toggle(isOn: $play)
                {
                    Text("")


                }
                .padding(.trailing, 30.0)
                .hueRotation(Angle.degrees(45))
                if play
                {
                    MyWatchView.self.playSound()
                }
            }
        }
```

It also has @State private var play = false; And a function playSound like this:

```
static private func playSound()
{
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.failure)
}
```

I am getting an error of Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols I think this is probably something that I am not understanding in the way structs work in Swift.
 I am trying to use a timer to trigger the play sound function. This is my code in my View Controller Class from my iOS storyboard app `timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: click class, selector: #selector(clickClass.repeatSound), userInfo: clickClass, repeats: switchView.isOn)`

Comment: Your error is probably caused by a scoping / {} issue. Please edit your question to show the code blocks in their full context. Also, to,access a static function just use `MyWatchView.playSound()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are doing this:

```swift
if play
{
    MyWatchView.self.playSound()
}
```

in a context where only `View`s are expected. The return type of the function is `Void` (or `()`), which is why you are getting the error.

---

If you want to *just* play a sound when you click the `Toggle`, you probably want to use a `Button` instead:

```swift
Button(action: {
    MyWatchView.self.playSound()
}) {
    Text("")
}
```

If you want a `Toggle` (e.g., to update a `Bool` variable), you can do this:

```swift
Toggle(isOn: $play)
{
    Text("")
}
.padding(.trailing, 30.0)
.hueRotation(Angle.degrees(45))
.onTapGesture {
    MyWatchView.self.playSound()
}
```